# Bintray "Not allowed" when uploading a project with packaging "maven-plugin"

Tags: maven, bintray

Good day.

I have a project, which was configured to be deployed to Bintray long time ago, and since then release deployment worked just fine. It was, till the moment I added new Maven submodule for my Maven plugin. After that, deployment start failing straight at the new module.

POM file: https://github.com/project-avral/oo-atom/blob/master/atom-maven-plugin/pom.xml

Maven traces part representing a failure:

```
[INFO] --- maven-deploy-plugin:2.8.2:deploy (default-deploy) @ atom-maven-plugin ---
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.8.2:deploy from plugin realm ClassRealm[plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.8.2, parent: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@70dea4e]
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.8.2:deploy' with basic configurator -->
[DEBUG]   (f) artifact = oo:atom-maven-plugin:maven-plugin:0.0.0
[DEBUG]   (f) attachedArtifacts = [oo:atom-maven-plugin:java-source:sources:0.0.0, oo:atom-maven-plugin:javadoc:javadoc:0.0.0]
[DEBUG]   (f) deployAtEnd = false
[DEBUG]   (s) localRepository =       id: local
      url: file:///home/skapral/.m2/repository/
   layout: default
snapshots: [enabled => true, update => always]
 releases: [enabled => true, update => always]

[DEBUG]   (f) offline = false
[DEBUG]   (f) packaging = maven-plugin
[DEBUG]   (f) pomFile = /home/skapral/GitHub/oo-atom/atom-maven-plugin/pom.xml
[DEBUG]   (f) project = MavenProject: oo:atom-maven-plugin:0.0.0 @ /home/skapral/GitHub/oo-atom/atom-maven-plugin/pom.xml
[DEBUG]   (f) reactorProjects = [MavenProject: oo:oo-atom:0.0.0 @ /home/skapral/GitHub/oo-atom/pom.xml, MavenProject: oo:atom-basis:0.0.0 @ /home/skapral/GitHub/oo-atom/atom-basis/pom.xml, MavenProject: oo:atom-api:0.0.0 @ /home/skapral/GitHub/oo-atom/atom-api/pom.xml, MavenProject: oo:atom-tests:0.0.0 @ /home/skapral/GitHub/oo-atom/atom-tests/pom.xml, MavenProject: oo:atom-maven-plugin:0.0.0 @ /home/skapral/GitHub/oo-atom/atom-maven-plugin/pom.xml, MavenProject: oo:atom-starter:0.0.0 @ /home/skapral/GitHub/oo-atom/atom-starter/pom.xml, MavenProject: oo:atom-it:0.0.0 @ /home/skapral/GitHub/oo-atom/atom-it/pom.xml, MavenProject: oo:atom-samples:0.0.0 @ /home/skapral/GitHub/oo-atom/atom-samples/pom.xml, MavenProject: oo:fibonacci:0.0.0 @ /home/skapral/GitHub/oo-atom/atom-samples/fibonacci/pom.xml, MavenProject: oo:todo:0.0.0 @ /home/skapral/GitHub/oo-atom/atom-samples/todo/pom.xml, MavenProject: oo:atomizer:0.0.0 @ /home/skapral/GitHub/oo-atom/atomizer/pom.xml]
[DEBUG]   (f) retryFailedDeploymentCount = 1
[DEBUG]   (f) skip = false
[DEBUG]   (f) updateReleaseInfo = false
[DEBUG] -- end configuration --
[DEBUG] Using transporter WagonTransporter with priority -1.0 for https://api.bintray.com/maven/skapral/oo-maven/oo-atom/;publish=1
[DEBUG] Using connector BasicRepositoryConnector with priority 0.0 for https://api.bintray.com/maven/skapral/oo-maven/oo-atom/;publish=1 with username=skapral, password=***
Uploading to bintray-skapral-oo-maven: https://api.bintray.com/maven/skapral/oo-maven/oo-atom/;publish=1/oo/atom-maven-plugin/0.0.0/atom-maven-plugin-0.0.0.jar
Uploaded to bintray-skapral-oo-maven: https://api.bintray.com/maven/skapral/oo-maven/oo-atom/;publish=1/oo/atom-maven-plugin/0.0.0/atom-maven-plugin-0.0.0.jar (8.4 kB at 2.5 kB/s)
Uploading to bintray-skapral-oo-maven: https://api.bintray.com/maven/skapral/oo-maven/oo-atom/;publish=1/oo/atom-maven-plugin/0.0.0/atom-maven-plugin-0.0.0.pom
Uploaded to bintray-skapral-oo-maven: https://api.bintray.com/maven/skapral/oo-maven/oo-atom/;publish=1/oo/atom-maven-plugin/0.0.0/atom-maven-plugin-0.0.0.pom (1.6 kB at 457 B/s)
Downloading from bintray-skapral-oo-maven: https://api.bintray.com/maven/skapral/oo-maven/oo-atom/;publish=1/oo/atom-maven-plugin/maven-metadata.xml
[DEBUG] Could not find metadata oo:atom-maven-plugin/maven-metadata.xml in bintray-skapral-oo-maven (https://api.bintray.com/maven/skapral/oo-maven/oo-atom/;publish=1)
[DEBUG] Writing tracking file /home/skapral/.m2/repository/oo/atom-maven-plugin/resolver-status.properties
Downloading from bintray-skapral-oo-maven: https://api.bintray.com/maven/skapral/oo-maven/oo-atom/;publish=1/oo/maven-metadata.xml
Downloaded from bintray-skapral-oo-maven: https://api.bintray.com/maven/skapral/oo-maven/oo-atom/;publish=1/oo/maven-metadata.xml (52 B at 20 B/s)
[DEBUG] Writing tracking file /home/skapral/.m2/repository/oo/resolver-status.properties
Uploading to bintray-skapral-oo-maven: https://api.bintray.com/maven/skapral/oo-maven/oo-atom/;publish=1/oo/atom-maven-plugin/maven-metadata.xml
Uploaded to bintray-skapral-oo-maven: https://api.bintray.com/maven/skapral/oo-maven/oo-atom/;publish=1/oo/atom-maven-plugin/maven-metadata.xml (326 B at 98 B/s)
Uploading to bintray-skapral-oo-maven: https://api.bintray.com/maven/skapral/oo-maven/oo-atom/;publish=1/oo/maven-metadata.xml
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] oo-atom 0.0.0 ...................................... SUCCESS [ 12.691 s]
[INFO] atom-basis ......................................... SUCCESS [01:13 min]
[INFO] atom-api ........................................... SUCCESS [ 12.651 s]
[INFO] atom-tests ......................................... SUCCESS [ 12.133 s]
[INFO] atom-maven-plugin .................................. FAILURE [ 16.279 s]
[INFO] atom-starter ....................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] atom-it ............................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] atom-samples ....................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] fibonacci .......................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] todo ............................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] atomizer 0.0.0 ..................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 02:07 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-06-02T02:07:32+03:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.8.2:deploy (default-deploy) on project atom-maven-plugin: Failed to deploy metadata: Could not transfer metadata oo/maven-metadata.xml from/to bintray-skapral-oo-maven (https://api.bintray.com/maven/skapral/oo-maven/oo-atom/;publish=1): Failed to transfer file: https://api.bintray.com/maven/skapral/oo-maven/oo-atom/;publish=1/oo/maven-metadata.xml. Return code is: 400, ReasonPhrase: Bad Request. -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.8.2:deploy (default-deploy) on project atom-maven-plugin: Failed to deploy metadata: Could not transfer metadata oo/maven-metadata.xml from/to bintray-skapral-oo-maven (https://api.bintray.com/maven/skapral/oo-maven/oo-atom/;publish=1): Failed to transfer file: https://api.bintray.com/maven/skapral/oo-maven/oo-atom/;publish=1/oo/maven-metadata.xml. Return code is: 400, ReasonPhrase: Bad Request.
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Failed to deploy metadata: Could not transfer metadata oo/maven-metadata.xml from/to bintray-skapral-oo-maven (https://api.bintray.com/maven/skapral/oo-maven/oo-atom/;publish=1): Failed to transfer file: https://api.bintray.com/maven/skapral/oo-maven/oo-atom/;publish=1/oo/maven-metadata.xml. Return code is: 400, ReasonPhrase: Bad Request.
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.deploy.DeployMojo.deployProject (DeployMojo.java:284)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.deploy.DeployMojo.execute (DeployMojo.java:169)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.artifact.deployer.ArtifactDeploymentException: Failed to deploy metadata: Could not transfer metadata oo/maven-metadata.xml from/to bintray-skapral-oo-maven (https://api.bintray.com/maven/skapral/oo-maven/oo-atom/;publish=1): Failed to transfer file: https://api.bintray.com/maven/skapral/oo-maven/oo-atom/;publish=1/oo/maven-metadata.xml. Return code is: 400, ReasonPhrase: Bad Request.
    at org.apache.maven.artifact.deployer.DefaultArtifactDeployer.deploy (DefaultArtifactDeployer.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.deploy.AbstractDeployMojo.deploy (AbstractDeployMojo.java:171)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.deploy.DeployMojo.deployProject (DeployMojo.java:250)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.deploy.DeployMojo.execute (DeployMojo.java:169)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.deployment.DeploymentException: Failed to deploy metadata: Could not transfer metadata oo/maven-metadata.xml from/to bintray-skapral-oo-maven (https://api.bintray.com/maven/skapral/oo-maven/oo-atom/;publish=1): Failed to transfer file: https://api.bintray.com/maven/skapral/oo-maven/oo-atom/;publish=1/oo/maven-metadata.xml. Return code is: 400, ReasonPhrase: Bad Request.
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDeployer.deploy (DefaultDeployer.java:326)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDeployer.deploy (DefaultDeployer.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.deploy (DefaultRepositorySystem.java:384)
    at org.apache.maven.artifact.deployer.DefaultArtifactDeployer.deploy (DefaultArtifactDeployer.java:142)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.deploy.AbstractDeployMojo.deploy (AbstractDeployMojo.java:171)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.deploy.DeployMojo.deployProject (DeployMojo.java:250)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.deploy.DeployMojo.execute (DeployMojo.java:169)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.MetadataTransferException: Could not transfer metadata oo/maven-metadata.xml from/to bintray-skapral-oo-maven (https://api.bintray.com/maven/skapral/oo-maven/oo-atom/;publish=1): Failed to transfer file: https://api.bintray.com/maven/skapral/oo-maven/oo-atom/;publish=1/oo/maven-metadata.xml. Return code is: 400, ReasonPhrase: Bad Request.
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.MetadataTransportListener.transferFailed (MetadataTransportListener.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$TaskRunner.run (BasicRepositoryConnector.java:365)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector.put (BasicRepositoryConnector.java:298)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDeployer.deploy (DefaultDeployer.java:320)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDeployer.deploy (DefaultDeployer.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.deploy (DefaultRepositorySystem.java:384)
    at org.apache.maven.artifact.deployer.DefaultArtifactDeployer.deploy (DefaultArtifactDeployer.java:142)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.deploy.AbstractDeployMojo.deploy (AbstractDeployMojo.java:171)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.deploy.DeployMojo.deployProject (DeployMojo.java:250)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.deploy.DeployMojo.execute (DeployMojo.java:169)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.wagon.TransferFailedException: Failed to transfer file: https://api.bintray.com/maven/skapral/oo-maven/oo-atom/;publish=1/oo/maven-metadata.xml. Return code is: 400, ReasonPhrase: Bad Request.
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.wagon.shared.AbstractHttpClientWagon.put (AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:635)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.wagon.shared.AbstractHttpClientWagon.put (AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:557)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.wagon.shared.AbstractHttpClientWagon.put (AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:539)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.wagon.shared.AbstractHttpClientWagon.put (AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:533)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.wagon.shared.AbstractHttpClientWagon.put (AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:513)
    at org.eclipse.aether.transport.wagon.WagonTransporter$PutTaskRunner.run (WagonTransporter.java:686)
    at org.eclipse.aether.transport.wagon.WagonTransporter.execute (WagonTransporter.java:435)
    at org.eclipse.aether.transport.wagon.WagonTransporter.put (WagonTransporter.java:418)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$PutTaskRunner.runTask (BasicRepositoryConnector.java:512)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$TaskRunner.run (BasicRepositoryConnector.java:360)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector.put (BasicRepositoryConnector.java:298)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDeployer.deploy (DefaultDeployer.java:320)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDeployer.deploy (DefaultDeployer.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.deploy (DefaultRepositorySystem.java:384)
    at org.apache.maven.artifact.deployer.DefaultArtifactDeployer.deploy (DefaultArtifactDeployer.java:142)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.deploy.AbstractDeployMojo.deploy (AbstractDeployMojo.java:171)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.deploy.DeployMojo.deployProject (DeployMojo.java:250)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.deploy.DeployMojo.execute (DeployMojo.java:169)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :atom-maven-plugin
```